# Как в sсroll зафиксировать рамку?

Tags: android, activity

У меня есть горизонтальный scroll, а как можно добавить не двигающуюся рамку по середине, чтобы после скролла, если картинке в рамке нету она бы докручивалась (код чуть ниже)

[image: Картинки с scroll]

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView24"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView23"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView22"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView21"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView20"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView19"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте кастомный `View`, унаследовав `HorizontalScrollView`, и переопределите в нем метод `onDraw()`, в котором и рисуйте рамку.
Докручивать - ловить момент прекращения скроллинга, определять позицию `ImageView` и перерисовывать рамку  несколько раз до нужной позиции.